# Value change notification inside Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15593/) when an item's option value is changed I would like to call `submitOption` function of my service.

Is it possible to do so without using `ng-click`/`ng-change` or modifying anything inside the `form` element?

I'm new to angular and probably not doing it the right way. But my goal here is to 'watch' item's value programmatically and submit it to the server once it got changed.

I'm aware of `$scope.watch()`, but I've read it's not a good idea to pass scope into a service

Comment: @PSL 2 issues come to mind: that part of a form might use some generic directive with no `ng-click` support and/or something else might change item's option value and I would like to handle all those changes in one place.

Comment: btw `but I've read it's not a good idea to pass scope into a service` You dont have to if at all you plan to create a watch. just watch it in the controller and call the service method. btw even if you plan to create a directive, you need not put logic inside it, instead you could expose function binding (&) so that consumer can plan what to do when something happens. You could easily bind it to ng-change inside directive and call the bound function.

Comment: In the point of MVC structure design, I recommend that you should not try to handle changes of a presentation value in *Service* layer. That is a work of *Controller* layer. Threfore I agree @PSL. `watch it in  the contoroller and call the service method.`

Comment: @PSL thanks, i'm gonna take a look at `&` binding. Meanwhile would you care to post an answer, so I can accept it?
@yazaki fair enough, but I'm not sure how would a watch on a dynamic array work (items can be added and removed from it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$watch` in the controller instead of the Service:

```
$scope.records.items.forEach(watchRecordValue);

function watchRecordValue(record){
    $scope.$watch(function(){ return record.option; }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(newVal !== oldVal){
            $scope.records.submitOption(record);
        }
    });
}
```

However, I think the above is a crazy work-around, and definitely should be avoided.

It would be significantly cleaner, easier to maintain, and faster to use - as you mentioned that you're avoiding - `ng-change`. In fact, you'd simply have to change the input tag on your HTML to:

```
<input name="options" 
       type="radio" 
       ng-model="item.option" 
       ng-change="records.submitOption(item)" 
       ng-value="option.id" />
```

(The `ng-change="records.submitOption(item)"` part is the only difference.)

**EDIT (Added "wrapper" solution):**

If modifying the form is really not feasible, you can wrap the form in your own directive. Here's a contrived example:

```
myApp.directive('myWatch', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myWatch: '=',
            myHandler: '@',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('myWatch', function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(newVal !== oldVal){
                    // Parent because we've created a scope for this directive
                    scope.$parent.$eval(attr.myHandler); // Copied from ngChange...
                }            
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now you can leave your form unchanged by wrapping it:

```
<div my-watch="item.option" my-handler="records.submitOption(item)">
    <form> <!-- your old form contents go here --> </form>
</div>
```

Here's your JSFiddle modified with this wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/shjejb34/

Note: almost everybody reading this should just do the `ng-change` solution above this. The wrapper directive is reinventing the wheel, replicating *good* functionality that Angular has already provided for us.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer with multiple alternative solutions. I ended up extending my generic directive with a callback function as PSL suggested above.